# How to generate a styled image with out actually creating it?

Tags: 7, media

There is a content type in my website called `image` and it has an *image* field. There are about 16GB images in my website and people have uploaded very high quality images.

There is an image style in my website which uses the original image plus a watermark. This causes double space consuming. People are only allowed to download this version. The number of images in my website is growing very fast and it needs lots of space.

I need to show the styled version to the user with out creating it in `\styled` directory.

Is there any way to handle this problem? Is there anyway to keep the site working like now, but instead of creating a separate copy of the original image, display the styled image and generate download link to the user in any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way would be to use CSS and put a div with a background transparent image of the watermark overlay on top of the actual image using the `z-index:` attribute.

You would risk that people could inspect element or view page source and find the direct link to the image, or use a tool to strip all css and then save the image.

For total security, I'm pretty sure there is no other way than having the watermark on the image itself.